# Duplicate Pandas dataframe rows by swapping two columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Given a pandas dataframe, each row in the dataframe should be duplicated, but the duplicate row differs from the original row in terms of the `score1` and `score2` columns whereby their values are swapped. Furthermore, the incremental nature of unique ID must be kept.

Original dataframe:

```
nme = ["Tom", "John", "Philip", "Ross"]
deg = ["MBA", "BCA", "M.Tech", "MBA"]
scr1 = [90, 40, 80, 98]
scr2 = [10, 20, 30, 50]

# dictionary of lists
dct = {'name': nme, 'degree': deg, 'score1': scr1, 'score2': scr2}
my_dataframe = pd.DataFrame(dct)
print(my_dataframe)

     name  degree  score1  score2
0     Tom     MBA      90      10
1    John     BCA      40      20
2  Philip  M.Tech      80      30
3    Ross     MBA      98      50
```

Expected dataframe:

```
nme = ["Tom","Tom", "John", "John", "Philip","Philip", "Ross", "Ross"]
deg = ["MBA", "MBA", "BCA", "BCA", "M.Tech", "M.Tech", "MBA", "MBA"]
scr1 = [90, 10, 40, 20, 80, 30, 98, 50]
scr2 = [10, 90, 20, 40, 30, 80, 50, 98]

# dictionary of lists
dct = {'name': nme, 'degree': deg, 'score1': scr1, 'score2': scr2}
my_new_dataframe = pd.DataFrame(dct)
print(my_new_dataframe)

     name  degree  score1  score2
0     Tom     MBA      90      10
1     Tom     MBA      10      90
2    John     BCA      40      20
3    John     BCA      20      40
4  Philip  M.Tech      80      30
5  Philip  M.Tech      30      80
6    Ross     MBA      98      50
7    Ross     MBA      50      98
```

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: it's better to avoid the python word `dict` as a variable name, i've corrected for you in the question

Answer (score 1):

This one works for me:

```
new_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['name', 'degree', 'score1', 'score2'])
j=0
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    new_df.loc[j] = [row[0], row[1], row[2], row[3]]
    new_df.loc[j+1] = [row[0], row[1], row[3], row[2]]
    j+=2
new_df
```

The Output:

```
name     degree score1  score2
0   Tom     MBA     90  10
1   Tom     MBA     10  90
2   John    BCA     40  20
3   John    BCA     20  40
4   Philip  M.Tech  80  30
5   Philip  M.Tech  30  80
6   Ross    MBA     98  50
7   Ross    MBA     50  98
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `itertools.permutations` and `df.explode` to get your desired output.

```
from itertools import permutations

my_dataframe['combine'] = [list(permutations((i,j),2)) for i,j in zip(my_dataframe.score1,my_dataframe.score2)]

     name  degree  score1  score2               combine
0     Tom     MBA      90      10  [(90, 10), (10, 90)]
1    John     BCA      40      20  [(40, 20), (20, 40)]
2  Philip  M.Tech      80      30  [(80, 30), (30, 80)]
3    Ross     MBA      98      50  [(98, 50), (50, 98)]

my_new_dataframe = my_dataframe.explode('combine') 

     name  degree  score1  score2   combine
0     Tom     MBA      90      10  (90, 10)
0     Tom     MBA      90      10  (10, 90)
1    John     BCA      40      20  (40, 20)
1    John     BCA      40      20  (20, 40)
2  Philip  M.Tech      80      30  (80, 30)
2  Philip  M.Tech      80      30  (30, 80)
3    Ross     MBA      98      50  (98, 50)
3    Ross     MBA      98      50  (50, 98)

my_new_dataframe[['score1','score2']] = pd.DataFrame(my_new_dataframe['combine'].tolist(), index= my_new_dataframe.index)

     name  degree  score1  score2   combine
0     Tom     MBA      90      10  (90, 10)
0     Tom     MBA      10      90  (10, 90)
1    John     BCA      40      20  (40, 20)
1    John     BCA      20      40  (20, 40)
2  Philip  M.Tech      80      30  (80, 30)
2  Philip  M.Tech      30      80  (30, 80)
3    Ross     MBA      98      50  (98, 50)
3    Ross     MBA      50      98  (50, 98)
```

### Update

To obtain unique index for every row, you can use `df.reset_index`

```
my_new_dataframe.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)

     name  degree  score1  score2   combine
0     Tom     MBA      90      10  (90, 10)
1     Tom     MBA      90      10  (10, 90)
2    John     BCA      10      90  (40, 20)
3    John     BCA      10      90  (20, 40)
4  Philip  M.Tech      40      20  (80, 30)
5  Philip  M.Tech      40      20  (30, 80)
6    Ross     MBA      20      40  (98, 50)
7    Ross     MBA      20      40  (50, 98)
```

Comment: Nice, thank you very much, however unique ID-s are duplicated in this case. Do you have a solution for that if I wanted to keep it unique?

Comment: Just to clarify, do you mean you just need one unique ID  with the two rows of scores? Or you are fine with one row of scores but two columns of tuples?

Comment: By unique ID I mean the firs column that is now 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, I actually prefer to have it like 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, everything else is perfect.

Comment: Glad to help :D please mark my answer too if it works for you

Answer (score 0):

Just realised it's been 4 days, but I've thought of a simple solution to swap the 2 scores columns first, before concat with the original dataframe, for example:

```
print(my_dataframe)
     name  degree  score1  score2
0     Tom     MBA      90      10
1    John     BCA      40      20
2  Philip  M.Tech      80      30
3    Ross     MBA      98      50

my_dataframe2 = my_dataframe.copy()
my_dataframe2.columns = ['name', 'degree', 'score2', 'score1']

print(my_dataframe2)
     name  degree  score2  score1    #note 2 column names are swapped
0     Tom     MBA      90      10
1    John     BCA      40      20
2  Philip  M.Tech      80      30
3    Ross     MBA      98      50
```

Next use `pd.concat()`, which will stack vertically based on column names:

```
df = pd.concat([my_dataframe, my_dataframe2]).sort_index().reset_index(drop=True)
print(df)

   degree    name  score1  score2
0     MBA     Tom      90      10
1     MBA     Tom      10      90
2     BCA    John      40      20
3     BCA    John      20      40
4  M.Tech  Philip      80      30
5  M.Tech  Philip      30      80
6     MBA    Ross      98      50
7     MBA    Ross      50      98
```